# How do i make prototyped class functions without creating publicly accessible Javascript variables using this

Tags: javascript

I write javascript all day, but I have a different style than others.  I was curious as to what are the differences in javascript in the 2 different implementations.

```
var ClassA = function(){
    var _value = 0;
    this.getValue = function(){ return _value; }
}
```

vs

```
var ClassB = function(){
    this._value = 0;
}
ClassB.prototype.getValue = function(){ return this._value; }
```

I see why based on javascript, prototypes would be used in inheritance.  I like it, but i dont like values being publicly available.

For example, when i instantiate `ClassB`, you can investigate and see _value inside it.  This makes it possible to be modified.

So, how would i go about making a prototype typed function like `ClassB` but hiding the properties of the object so they cant be changed, or logged, similar to `ClassA`

**Edit**  I did try to create `ClassB` without using `this`, but _value was not recognized in `getValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var ClassA = function(){
        var _value = 0;
        this.getValue = function(){ return _value; }
    }


  ClassA.prototype.greatGetValue = function() { return this.getValue(); };
```

Comment: So a workaround would be to create setters and getters for the variables and then only reference them there.  I like this answer a lot.  I dont like the idea of someone changing arb variables, but this would allow you to implement controls such that if they were to change a variable with the function, it would update anything which correlates respectively.